# Swift: Detect any change in screen

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if it was possible to detect the slightest change on the screen (UIView redraw, text changes, tableview reload, etc.) without looking at each view 1 by 1 (or add some code in each view)

Maybe NSNotification or other things like that. I did not find on google ... (Maybe it's not possible or I do not have the right words to find that)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this for snapshot UI testing?

Comment: Can you be specific about which changes you want to detect?

Comment: @Aaron Any changes that affect the view, limit if I could detect any pixel that changes

Comment: @Alexander I would like to take screenshots with every change of view

Comment: Taking a screenshot whenever a "view changes" seems like a separate question/issue. But that's just me.

Comment: @Aaron I already have a function to make an image of the entire view. I just need to know when the view is updated to call my function again.

Comment: Not sure Apple would look kindly on a pixel-level change detection. The idea could be easily abused. Imagine monitoring the pixels in the banner area of the screen and taking a screen shot whenever the user receives a notification. I would think your best bet is to simply track a set of the mutable views and setup a new protocol to monitor for changes.

Comment: @MarinBurazzi That doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, what you're trying to build is the solution to track the user behaviour while using the app. Taking screenshots on every minor change in app screen is not the appropriate solution, instead take the screenshot on some predefined events of the app, or between some predefined time interval might be the feasible solution.

Iphone transitions are rendered at the rate of 60 fps. Even if you get to know a way to detect every minor change in screen, generating 60 screenshots in 1 sec is not an optimal solution.

Comment: I do not want to take as many screenshots ^^

It would be :
- detect that the view changes
- wait for it to stabilize
- and take a screenshot.

  So we would not have the 60 screenshots per second.